# SQL server Installation - SQL server agent is enabled by default?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

When SQL server is installed on a machine, is the SQL Server Agent enabled and running by default, or does it need starting manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an installation option. In the installer GUI or command line you can leave it as enabled or disabled and automatic or manual. By default in most versions of SQL it is not enabled and started. I always change it when installing - or forget and do it shortly thereafter.

Comment: So you mean to say that in GUI under server configuration -- service accounts I can see their is an option to select as manual or automatic. If I select automatic and once the installation is completed my SQL Agent will run automatically and in manual I have to go to services and run it ?

Comment: Precisely what I meant. The "startup type" option would be automatic. And it would be started upon successful completion of installation.